# PHP Handling API to not exceed its limit?

Tags: php, api, function, caching, oauth

I was wondering what can I do to not do multiple calls to API? For instance, if I'm trying to use yelp's api, they have a limit of calls before exceeding (they stop giving you information once you exceed that number).

What can I do? Right now, I have this (from their API PHP example) in every page that I require to get information from their site:

```
// For example, request business with id 'the-waterboy-sacramento'
//$unsigned_url = "http://api.yelp.com/v2/business/the-waterboy-sacramento";


// For examaple, search for 'tacos' in 'sf'
//$unsigned_url = "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=tacos&location=sf";

// My own code
$unsigned_url = "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=".$term."";
// $term is coming from searching

// Set your keys here
$consumer_key = "some_id";
$consumer_secret = "some_id";
$token = "some_id";
$token_secret = "some_id";

// Token object built using the OAuth library
$token = new OAuthToken($token, $token_secret);

// Consumer object built using the OAuth library
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

// Yelp uses HMAC SHA1 encoding
$signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();

// Build OAuth Request using the OAuth PHP library. Uses the consumer and token object created above.
$oauthrequest = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $token, 'GET', $unsigned_url);

// Sign the request
$oauthrequest->sign_request($signature_method, $consumer, $token);

// Get the signed URL
$signed_url = $oauthrequest->to_url();

// Send Yelp API Call
$ch = curl_init($signed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch); // Yelp response
curl_close($ch);
```

And this seems excessive to be doing in EVERY page when I want to call a certain business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use it but, as a general answer, **consider caching the data in a database to reduce API calls**. It will also improve your site's performance, especially if the same page that needs the same data from the API loads multiple times.

**HERE'S A FILE BASED GENERAL USE IMPLEMENTATION**

```
/**
* Cache friendly function call stub.
* 
* @param callback $Callback
* @param array $Arguments
* @param integer $Expiration
* @return mixed
*/
function CallFunctionAndCacheResult($Callback, array $Arguments, $Expiration = 3600){
    // Validate $Callback
    if(!is_callable($Callback)){
        trigger_error('$Callback must be a callback.', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    // Validate $Arguments (we need some to hash)
    if(empty($Arguments)){
        trigger_error('$Arguments cannot be empty.', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    // Empty $Expiration means live calls
    if(empty($Expiration)){
        return call_user_func_array($Callback, $Arguments);
    }
    // Validate $Expiration (we need some to hash)
    if(!is_numeric($Expiration) or (($Expiration = intval($Expiration)) < 1)){
        trigger_error('$Expiration has to be a positive integer.', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    // Hash the Arguments (Unique Call ID)
    $Hash = md5(serialize($Arguments));
    // Check if Cache file exists
    if(is_file($Cache = dirname(__FILE__)."/{$Hash}.serial")){
        // Test if file expired
        if(($MTime = filemtime($Cache)) >= (time() - $Expiration)){
            // Attempt to load data, assume it's corrupted
            if(($Data = unserialize(file_get_contents($Cache))) !== false){
                return $Data;
            }
        }
    }
    // Now regenerate the data if you got here
    $Data = call_user_func_array($Callback, $Arguments);
    // Store it, with  LOCK_EX enabled to prevent collisions
    file_put_contents($Cache, serialize($Data), LOCK_EX);
    // Return the data
    return $Data;
}

// Test case (store current time for 10 seconds, keep refreshing)
var_dump($Data = CallFunctionAndCacheResult(function(){
    // Return some data to be cached
    return array_merge(func_get_args(), array(
        'cached'    => gmstrftime('%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S'),
    ));
}, array(
    'Username',
    'Password',
    // ...
), 10));
```

**Hope it makes sense.** Just test it, figure it out and use a DB engine to achieve the same result.

Comment: do you have any references that i can look into? Thanks

Comment: @andrewliu Not really, it's natural for me... and I'm a bad teacher :) You have to get in the middle of the API call and cache to database. Then, on future calls, check if arguments hash match and return the result from the DB instead of doing a live call... but also set an expire time so you eventually refresh the data. You need to use a database and a function to handle the call to allow easy caching. Look into the mysqli object and start from there. But maybe you'll find tips here on SO.

Comment: So my code would still have to be in every page? But I would need to add the caching into each page as well?

Comment: @andrewliu It all depends on your design. But I would write a function (or more to handle your API call) and place it in a file and include that file where you need the function used to query API. And then call the function with different arguments based on the page you are on and the data that needs to be retrieved on that page. Repetitive code goes into functions that stay in includes that are include_once globally usually.

Comment: Please note that the Yelp API Terms Of Use seem to prohibit caching: "You agree that you will not... cache, record, pre-fetch, or otherwise store any portion of the Yelp Content..." http://www.yelp.com/developers/getting_started/api_terms

Answer (score 1):

Caching is your friend here. When you think you are doing unwanted API Queries over and over again, you should cache the information, either to a cookie if its something so minor/non critical or else to a database.

Like, I dont want to run out of the limit if a user wish to refresh a page where I run a query to get his name. You can get his name once, store it to a cookie, and use it from then instead of querying everytime. Like the other answer says, Faster, and efficient.